# Adding an element between existing elements in vector

Tags: clojure

I have a vector like this:

```
[1 2 "b" 4 5 6 "c" 8 9 10]
```

I want to add letter "a" between every element, so that the end result looks like this:

```
[1 "a" 2 "a" "b" "a" 4 "a" 5 "a" 6 "a" "c" "a" 9 "a" 10]
```

What is the best way to do this in Clojure?

Note that the letter "a" should never be the first or last element in the vector, it should only appear between other elements.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
user> (interpose "a" input)
(1 "a" 2 "a" "b" "a" 4 "a" 5 "a" 6 "a" "c" "a" 8 "a" 9 "a" 10)
```

Or if the output has to be a vector, then

```
user> (vec (interpose "a" input))
[1 "a" 2 "a" "b" "a" 4 "a" 5 "a" 6 "a" "c" "a" 8 "a" 9 "a" 10]
```

Here is the documentation for `interpose`: https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/interpose

Comment: Awesome! I didn't know there was a function to do just that. :)